# How to render a component according to the route using GatsbyJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, gatsby

I'm using `GatsbyJS` and I'm trying to render a different `header` according to the route of the URL.

Example :

`mydomain.com/` => should render `HeaderLanding`

`mydomain.com/blog` => should render `HeaderMain`

Does anyone know the proper way to create a conditional rendering to display a component according to the route in the `layout.js` file?

Thank you for your support.

```
// layout.js

import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import HeaderLanding from "./header-landing"
import HeaderMain from "./header-main"
import Footer from "./footer"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much what @ravibagul91 have answered, however Gatsby doesn't use `react-router-dom`.

If `Layout` is a page component, Gatsby will pass it a `location` prop. You can extract `location.pathname` & apply your logic there

```
const Layout = ({ children, location }) => {
  const isMain = location.pathname === 'your-path'

  return (
    <>
      { isMain ? <HeaderMain> : <HeaderLanding> }
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

---

If `Layout` is not a page component, you can import the HOC `Location` from `@reach/router`:

```js
import { Location } from '@reach/router' // gatsby's dep

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Location>
       {({ location }) => (
         ...
       )}
    </Location>

  )
}
```

Or simply pass the `location` props from a Gatsby page component to this component from each page:

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'

export default ({ location }) => (
  <Layout location={location}>
    ...
  </Layout>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `location` object of [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = ({ children, location }) => {

  return (
    <>
      {location.pathname.split('/')[1] ==="blog" ? <HeaderMain /> : <HeaderLanding /> }
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default withRouter(Layout)
```

---

**Update**

**Gatsby v2** has switched routers from [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy) with [`@reach/router`](https://reach.tech/router)

From the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/migrating-from-v1-to-v2/#4-pass-history-location-and-match-props-to-layout),

> In v1, the layout component had access to history, location, and match props. In v2, only pages have access to these props. If you need these props in the layout component, pass them through from the page.

So your `Layout` component should be,

```
const Layout = ({ children, location }) => {

  return (
    <>
      {location.pathname.split('/')[1] ==="blog" ? <HeaderMain /> : <HeaderLanding /> }
      <div className="content-wrapper">
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

And your `Page` component should be, (just example)

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
export default props => (
  <Layout location={props.location}> //Pass location here
    <div>Hello World</div>
  </Layout>
)
```

**Or** you can use [`Location`](https://reach.tech/router/api/Location).

> Typically you only have access to the location in Route Components, Location provides the location anywhere in your app with a child render prop.

```
<Location>
  {props => {
    props.location
    props.navigate
  }}
</Location>

// usually folks use some destructuring
<Location>
  {({ location })=> {
    // ...
  }}
</Location>
```