# Gatsby location props not available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

According to the Gatsby docs the location props should be available to all components https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/.

My pages are under src/pages and are automatically routed using the `<Link>` inside the header component. However, the below code in the header component returns undefined:

```
const Header = ({ location }) => {

console.log(location)
```

Am i missing something? Do i need to explicitly pass down location props to header? As i interpreted the docs, this is done automatically.

An idea had - could it be due to my `{children}` pass in layout.js?

**Layout.js**

```
return (
<>
  <Header url={data.site.siteMetadata.siteUrl} />
  
  <main>{children}</main>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443187/how-to-render-a-component-according-to-the-route-using-gatsbyjs . It may help you to resolve the problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`location` property is available in top-level components (pages) so you should get it into a page and drill down into your `Header` or another component. As it is extracted from the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/#what-is-location-data):

> Sometimes it can be helpful to know exactly what your app’s browser
> URL is at any given stage. Because Gatsby uses [`@reach/router`](https://github.com/reach/router) for
> [client-side](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary#client-side) routing, the location prop is passed to **any page component**
> and represents where the app is currently

Because Gatsby extends from `@reach/router`, you can take advantage by using a `Layout` as a page component, in that case, `location` will be available in your `Layout` component, from there, you can lift it down to any desired children component.

In your scenario, the `Header` component by default, will never have the `location` data, you should have to pass it from where it's available.